# Javascript To do list - whats wrong in my code?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I have been watching a tutorial about how to make a to do list and so far my code is IDENTICAL to the one in the tutorial but still doesn't work-Ive been starring at the code for forever but can't figure out why..
my html (I don't have to include  etc because I was writing my code on codepen(javascript,html and css are already being combined):

```
<body>
  <h1>To Do List</h1>
   <p><button id="add">Add</button></p>

<ul id="todoList"></ul>
</body>
```

Javascript:

```
function addNewItem(){
  var  listItem = document.createElement ("li");
  listItem.innerText = "hello";
  var list = ducument.getElementById("todoList");
  list.appendChild(listItem);
 }
var btnNew = document.getElementById("add");
btnNew.onclick = addNewItem;
```

In the tutorial the same code works and when you click the add button "hello" is being displayed and in my code nothing happens when i click on the add button..

Comment: Use the F12 key to browse the developer tools in browsers console - it will help you with this in the future by isolating this invalid line.

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo on this line:

```
var list = ducument.getElementById("todoList");
```

It's `document`, not `ducument`.

See this working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/omgtoblerone/h2sL1vu8/

In most browsers, if you hit F12, you'll see an error console. If you had looked at the console, you would've seen the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: **ducument** is not defined

Easy fix!

Comment: OMG Thanks so much!!! I have been starring at my code for soo long and couldn't see that!

Comment: @learningcoding don't forget to accept the answer by clicking the tick to the left of the answer :)